# Stack Overflow rip-off?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I recently stumbled upon another one of those sites that just crawls content from other sites. It seems to be fairly new, doesn't contain any ads (yet) and still contains some "lorem ipsum":

[Original on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019011/c-developer-functions-that-can-only-be-called-by-other-developer-functions)

[AskToAnswer.com](http://asktoanswer.com/questions/c-developer-functions-that-can-only-be-called-by-other-developer-functions/)

Does Stack Overflow care about things like that / do something about it?